# How do I get my y-axis labels to reach the top of my plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I'm trying to get the y-axis to read out in 2.5% increments, i.e. 0, 2.5, 5, etc., but it neither does this nor even reach the top of the bar chart for Under 35.

[image: The y-axis for this bar chart does not reach the top of the plot.]

```
#Compare the overall net engagment between the two age groups
ad.analysis.age <- engagement %>% 
  group_by(age) %>%
  summarise(ppos = weighted.mean(Attentive.engagement, Impressions), 
            pneg = pmax(0, weighted.mean(responses - Attentive.engagement, Impressions)), 
            Impressions = sum(Impressions)) %>% 
  mutate(netp = ppos - pneg,
         marginoferror = 1.96 * ( 
           (ppos * (1 - ppos)) / Impressions + (pneg * (1 - pneg)) / Impressions))

#Plot the visualization
ggplot(ad.analysis.age, aes(x = age, y = netp, ymin = (netp - marginoferror), 
                                   ymax = (netp + marginoferror))) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 10), axis.title.y = element_text(size = 10)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = 0.6, fill = "#0A2240") + gpa_theme(10) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format()) +
  labs(x = NULL, y = "Net Attentive Engagement", title =
         "Ad Engagement by Age") +
  theme(aspect.ratio = 2.5/3) +
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(margin = unit(c(0, 3, 0, 0), "mm")))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `breaks` argument in `scale_y_continuous`:

```r
+ scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0,1,by = 0.025), labels = scales::percent_format())
```

Here an illustration using `iris` dataset:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% summarise(Mean = mean(Sepal.Length)/100) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Species, y = Mean))+
  geom_col( width = 0.6, fill = "#0A2240")+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0,1,by = 0.025), labels = scales::percent)
```

[image]

Does it answer your question ?